# How does this recursive SQL CTE work exactly?

Tags: sql, common-table-expression, recursive-query

Could someone explain to me how this SQL query works exactly?

```
WITH recursive n(n) AS (
  SELECT 2 n
  UNION ALL
  SELECT n+1 FROM n WHERE n<1000
)
SELECT a.n
FROM n a
  LEFT JOIN n b
  ON b.n < sqrt(a.n)
GROUP BY a.n
HAVING a.n=2 OR MIN(a.n % b.n) > 0;
```

This will generate the following in PostgresQL:

```
 n
====
251
887
601
647
577
...
9
(177 rows)
```

My understanding of the line-by-line breakdown:

`SELECT 2 n` -- select the number 2 as n [the anchor member of CTE]

`UNION ALL`  -- combine with recursive component n+1 from n<1000, so display all numbers from 2 to 1000

`SELECT a.n FROM n a` -- run the above query [the recursive member of CTE]

`LEFT JOIN n b` -- left join the numbers 2-1000 with a second set of numbers

`ON b.n < sqrt(a.n)` -- where the second set of numbers is less than the square root of the first column of numbers?

`GROUP BY a.n` -- only display the first column of numbers

`HAVING a.n=2 OR MIN(a.n. % b.n) > 0` -- ...where A=2 or the minimum of A modulo B is greater than 0?

It's a stupid query but any help in deciphering it would be appreciated.

Comment: i think the intention here is to generate prime numbers less than 1000. However, the results don't seem to confirm that as you get 25,49 etc.

Comment: looking closely at the results, i think your query generates all primes and their squares less than 1000. but you have to add one more condition in the `having` clause, `HAVING a.n=2 OR a.n =3 OR MIN(a.n % b.n) > 0` to include 3 in the results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query, when properly fixed, generates a list of primes below 1000:

```
WITH recursive n(n) AS (
  SELECT 2 n
  UNION ALL
  SELECT n+1 FROM n WHERE n<1000
)
SELECT a.n
FROM n a
  LEFT JOIN n b
  ON b.n <= sqrt(a.n)                        -- Fix #1
GROUP BY a.n
HAVING a.n=2 OR a.n=3 OR MIN(a.n % b.n) > 0  -- Fix #2
ORDER BY a.n ASC
```

[Demo.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/7239)

The explanation is rather straightforward: the recursive part of your query is simply a way to give you a list of numbers from 2, inclusive, to 1000, exclusive. You could replace the recursive clause with an actual table populated with consecutive integer numbers.

These numbers are then fed into the non-CTE part of your query, and joined to themselves on the condition `b.n < sqrt(a.n)`. The `a` side represents candidate primes; the `b` side represents candidate divisors.

Here is the first error in your query: `<` must be changed to `<=`, otherwise square roots of prime squares would be included into the output.

The `GROUP BY` groups potential primes with its candidate divisors into a single group. `HAVING` clause drops everything with one or more candidate divisors dividing the candidate prime evenly, i.e. where `MIN(a.n % b.n)` is zero.

This is where you need a second fix, because the square root of `3`, a prime number, is less than `2`, the smallest candidate divisor on the list. Hence, `3` ends up with no candidate divisors at all, and get thrown out by `HAVING` clause; you need to add `OR a.n=3` to preserve it.