# Getting a list of primes in a range using recursive cte

Tags: sql, recursion, common-table-expression

I'm trying to see how I get a list of prime numbers using a recursive cte. So far I am able to build a list of numbers:

```
with recursive range(i) as (
    select 1
    union all
    select i+1 from range
)
select i from range limit 100;
```

However, I've been a bit stuck on how for each number, to see if it's divisible by any smaller number (I don't care about efficiency, if the number is 17, it can check all numbers 2-16 for now).

Answer (score -1):

This might be a bit hackish but I did a cross join and checked whether the modulus of numerator over denominator ever equals zero:

```
with recursive range(i) as (
    select 1
    union all
    select i+1 from range
    where i < 20
)
select
    numerator.i,
    MIN(numerator.i % divisor.i)=0 is_divisible
FROM 
    range numerator, range divisor
WHERE 
    numerator.i > divisor.i
    AND divisor.i >= 2
GROUP BY
    numerator.i
HAVING
    is_divisible=false
```

Which gives me:

```
I   IS_DIVISIBLE
3   FALSE
5   FALSE
7   FALSE
11  FALSE
13  FALSE
17  FALSE
19  FALSE
```

Here is a better answer as well: [How does this recursive SQL CTE work exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36391833/how-does-this-recursive-sql-cte-work-exactly)